# Prefix and language Discord JS Command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I would like to make a multifunction discord bot, and I would like a command that automatically changes the prefix. If you know how to do it thank you for showing me to explain its operation, and if possible show me an order to do the same thing but with the language.
Thanks you.

Comment: Please give us some code that you have tried and why it doesn't work - we don't 'spoon-feed' programs here.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward:

```
var prefix = '!'
bot.on("message", function(message){
    let args = message.content.split(" ")
    if(args[0] === "!prefix") prefix = args[1]
}
```

Then the rest of your `on("message")` could look like

```
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix){
    //Execute command
}
```